# UITextView & UITextField get refreshed when pick image from camera from iPhone device

Tags: iphone, camera, uitextfield, refresh, uiimagepickercontroller

Facing some weird moment of my career. I have some uitextfield's and one uitextview in my UIViewController....everything works fine on simulator and iPhone 4 iOS v 4.3.5. But in iPhone 4 iOS v 4.0.1 sometimes I get whole view refreshed. That meant sometimes my uitextfields & uitextview lost text after picking image from camera.....

for solving this my attempt was when view disappear I saved values in some array..... and when view did appear i show array values to textboxes.....its works fine with simulator too. but this time my apps get stucked on iPhone 4 iOS v 4.0.1.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"title : %@",actionSheet.title);
    if (![actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Success"] && ![actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Error"] && ![actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"خطأ"]) {
        if(buttonIndex == 1) {
            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
            {
                UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
                picker.delegate = self;
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
                [picker release];
            }
        } else {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {

    float actualHeight = img.size.height;
    float actualWidth = img.size.width;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = 320.0/480.0;

    if(imgRatio!=maxRatio){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            imgRatio = 480.0 / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = 480.0;
        }
        else{
            imgRatio = 320.0 / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = 320.0;
        }
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [img drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(imageCount == 1){
        self.firstImage = image;
        self.previewImage1.image =firstImage;
    }else if(imageCount == 2){
        self.secondImage = image;
        self.previewImage2.image =secondImage;
    }else if(imageCount == 3){
        self.thirdImage = image;
        self.previewImage3.image =thirdImage;
    }else if(imageCount == 4){
        self.fourthImage = image;
        self.previewImage4.image =fourthImage;
    }
    [myImageNames replaceObjectAtIndex:imageCount-1 withObject:@"Assigned"];

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Paste the code you are having an issue with.

Comment: What do you mean by "my apps get stucked". Do you mean the application interface freezes and doesn't respond to touches during 2-3 seconds and then it continues to work normally?

Comment: just ignore about the stuck.... i get my uitextfield blank sometimes(not everytime) just after picking image from camera on iPhone 4 iOS v4.0.1 but not on simulator and iPhone 4 IOSv 4.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..Deleted app from device. then restarted device and install build again....
Now no problem with uitextfield refresh on picking image from camera..
chill guys....:-)